# Oracle - Setting column to NULL do not remove CHECK contraint

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I have NOT NULL column in my table and I need to allow null value. I know solution

```
alter table USER modify(FIRST_NAME null);
```

but it seems to not work in my case, because it do not remove existing 
`CHECK ("FIRST_NAME" IS NOT NULL)`. This constraint has system name SYSxxxxx so I also cannot directly disable this constraint (because name differs on enviroments). I assume it has something to do with fact that this table was created by loading DUMP into database (and for some reason, Oracle lose connection between column property and CHECK). Any idea how this happend and how to solve this?

Comment: Does the `alter` seem to work when it is executed, or does it error? Your table name can't really be `USER`, unless it's quoted, but you'd get an ORA-00932 if that was the issue.

Comment: I change table name, in real world it is not named `USER`. This alter finish without error, it remove `NOT NULL` from column definition but do not remove `CHECK(NOT NULL)`

Comment: Do you know if it had two apparently-identical (apart from the SYS_C name) constraints before did the alter? It can be in that state if you  explicitly created an `is not null` constraint, as well as setting the column to not-null, as vav showed. I seem to recall that seeing that happen by accident after an import or rebuild, but can't remember exactly which tool had an issue; I think dbms_metadata might do it sometimes. Do the other environments have two constraints? Maybe it isn't actually an issue for those?

Comment: There is only one constraint SYSxxxxxx. Table was created with NOT NULL column and no change has been done since then. Each enviroment have only one constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I come with this solution

```
alter table USER rename column FIRST_NAME to FIRST_NAME_OLD;
alter table USER ADD FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(40 CHAR) NULL;
update USER set first_name=first_name_old;
alter table USER drop column FIRST_NAME_OLD;
```

I know It may have performance issue on large tables, but that is not my case

Answer (score 3):

Creating NOT NULL constraint and CHECK:

```
create table tmp(
n1 number not null,
n2 number check (n2 is not null)
)
/
select * from all_constraints where table_name = 'TMP'
/
```

output (substract):

```
constraint_name   constraint_type   table_name   search_condition
---------------   ---------------   ----------   ----------------
SYS_C0036560      C                 TMP          "N1" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0036561      C                 TMP          n2 is not null
```

So, they look almost the same in a dictionary.

I think, you would need a script that would find constraint name by table/column combination and then (using dynamic sql) drop/disable it.

---

more thoughts :)   There is a difference! Could you check output from query below for your tables?

```
select column_name, NULLABLE from USER_TAB_COLS where table_name = 'TMP'

COLUMN_NAME                    NULLABLE
------------------------------ --------
N1                             N        
N2                             Y
```

After I do

```
alter table tmp drop constraint SYS_C0036560
```

N1 column is nullable:

```
COLUMN_NAME                    NULLABLE
------------------------------ --------
N1                             Y        
N2                             Y
```

If this works for you as well, then generate a script

```
select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' drop constraint ' || constraint_name || ';'
from all_constraints where table_name in ( 'TMP', 'list of your tables' )
and constraint_type = 'C' 
and instr(upper(search_condition, 'IS NOT NULL') > 0
and replace(
substr(upper(search_condition), 1, instr(search_condition, ' ')), 
'"', '')  in ('FIRST_NAME', 'maybe some other columns names')
```

Comment: `FIRST_NAME N` - it showing not nullable, but id definitely not allowing null values

Comment: N is not nullable. It should not allow nulls in this case. Or you tried to say something else? I am puzzled by 'but' in your sentence.

Comment: sorry for my grammar, it means null are not allowed, when inserting null, error is raised

Comment: @kuchi - then this seems inconsistent; you're saying that `user_tab_columns` has `NULLABLE=N`, but that describing the table does *not* say `NOT NULL`? Maybe you can add the query and output you're running, and the `describe`, to the question. Are you sure you're looking at the same table in the same schema?

Comment: @vav - than for your suggestions, when I drop SYSxxxxx constraint, NULL values are allowed. As I write before, I already solve this issue by copying values to new column...